# Defining tensor components generally

Tags: tensors

I would like to define a tensor according to its components, something like the following:

```
[F(x)]_i,j = Integrate[f(x,y)A_i(y)B_j(y),y]
```

where i and j are components between 1 and 3, i.e. A_i(y)B_j(y) is a 2nd rank tensor. F is also a 2nd rank tensor, with components i and j. Now, I don't want to explicitly enter the separate values for this definition, i.e.

```
[F(x)]_1,1 = Integrate[f(x,y)A_1(y)B_1(y),y]
[F(x)]_1,2 = Integrate[f(x,y)A_1(y)B_2(y),y]
```

etc. How can I do it generally? Also, I would not like to enter specific values for A and B components, but keep it general for arbitrary A and B.

---

#### EDIT

Suppose I have the following:

```
f = 5 x + 3 y;
A = {8 y^2, 5 y, 17 y^3 + 3};
B = {7 y + 3, 4 y, 5 y + 3 y^2};
```

Now, I don't know my exact input (that's what I am asking) but it would be something like that:

```
F[i,j]=Integrate[f A[[i]] B[[j]],{y,0,8}]
```

I want it to be defined as a tensor, so that later I will be able to contract its indices with other tensors. My output should look like:

```
F = {{Integrate [f*A[[1]] B[[1]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[1]] B[[2]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[1]] B[[3]], {y, 0, 8}]},
     {Integrate [f*A[[2]] B[[1]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[2]] B[[2]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[2]] B[[3]], {y, 0, 8}]},
     {Integrate [f*A[[3]] B[[1]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[3]] B[[2]], {y, 0, 8}], 
      Integrate [f*A[[3]] B[[3]], {y, 0, 8}]}}
```

I want this to work when I don't define explicitly `A`, `B`, `f`. without definitions, I want *Mathematica* to write the answer in terms of `A[[1]]` etc, and understand it as a tensor, so I can use it later. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Does `Array` or `Table` help?

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible without entering the values explicitly, i.e. writing the expression using i,j and their range (1-3) and the progra would know what the 9 values I mean are

Comment: Can you give a specific example of an input you might have and an output you would desire, so the question is completely clear?  Please use Mathematica code (what you posted is not).  I'm asking this because I can imagine a number of different interpretations of your question, based on Mathematica's capabilities. An example would help a lot and would save us both time (we won't have to have a long comment thread for clarifications).

Comment: BTW depending on how A and B are defined you may be able to use the `Listable` attribute, `Map` or `MapThread`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I posted an answer.  Does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Or using [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html):

```
Outer[Integrate[f #1 #2, {y, 0, 8}] &, A, B]
```

> ```
> {{5873664/5 + 307200 x, 3145728/5 + 163840 x, 3932160 + 991232 x},
>  {115200 + (96800 x)/3, 61440 + (51200 x)/3, 371712 + (294400 x)/3},
>  {83059424/5 + 4164232 x, 8919040 + 2230144 x, 399099392/7 + 13936480 x}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table` to achieve this:

```
f = 5 x + 3 y;
A = {8 y^2, 5 y, 17 y^3 + 3};
B = {7 y + 3, 4 y, 5 y + 3 y^2};

Table[Integrate[f a b, {y, 0, 8}], {a, A}, {b, B}]

(* {{5873664/5 + 307200 x, 3145728/5 + 163840 x, 
  3932160 + 991232 x}, {115200 + (96800 x)/3, 61440 + (51200 x)/3, 
  371712 + (294400 x)/3}, {83059424/5 + 4164232 x, 
  8919040 + 2230144 x, 399099392/7 + 13936480 x}} *)
```

Comment: Hey, when did `Outer` appear there? ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard About 1 second before you posted!  The "new answer" notifcation really came just after I pressed the post button ... sorry

Comment: If you include shorter form to satisfy my need for terse code I'll delete my redundant answer.